# PHP downloading .zip file but incorrectly

Tags: php

I am trying to download a zip file from a local server on to the HD.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($archive, ZipArchive::CREATE);

$files = scandir($dir);
unset($files[0], $files[1]);
foreach ($files as $file) {
$zip->addFile($dir.'/'.$file);
}
$zip->close();
$download=$archive;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Reports". $stocktake_id. ".zip");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

The file gets downloaded but the size of it is incorrect and it doesn't open properly, saying that the format is either invalid or file is corrupted.

Comment: did you checked you are getting data, what is in $files?

Comment: Your code only sets headers, so are we to assume that the output is actually empty?

Comment: The zip file gets generated correctly as I can check it on the local server. The reason why I want to be able to download it automatically is for the dum-dums in our company that don't know how to get the file from the server.

Comment: Why not redirecteding the browser to the URL containing the zip file?

Comment: @Tarik: I would imagine you would not want to expose the actual files to clients, to keep the paths unexposed.

Comment: @twicerj Can be taken care of through URL rewriting

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the content-type header.
Also, I don't see you echo'ing the raw data to the clientside?
And, make sure there is not debug output or anything that is not in the file itself.

```
//After you saved your file:

download_file_to_client($saved_file);
exit;

function download_file_to_client($file, $mime = 'application/zip')
{
    $filesize = filesize($file);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime.';charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="some-filename.zip"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
    flush(); // Get the headers out immediately to prevent any delay in some browsers.

    $fh = fopen($file, "r");
    while ($fh && !feof($fh))
    {
        echo fread($fh, 8192);
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: When I try this it seems to be looping forever? I take it that it is dependent on the size of the file but the zip file is only 287kb so I wouldn't expect it to take that long?

Just to be sure, a download dialog box should popup as with usual downloads yes?

Comment: That means that the file pointer $fh is not a correct pointer.
Please var_dump $fh and see if it is a Resource id. If not, it means the path to $file is not reachable the way you pass $file. 
I added some error handling to the function..

Comment: Try using an absolute path, to see what happens?

Comment: Please also try to add the following to the start of the main script, so php will not continue on any notice or error (in combination with error_reporting(E_ALL)):

    //Error handler for handling exceptions.
    set_error_handler(function($severity, $message, $file, $line)
    {
        if(!(error_reporting() & $severity))
        {
            return;
        }
        throw new ErrorException($message, $severity, $severity, $file, $line);
    });

Comment: I tried using the updated function and got this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'WKPDF system error:
Error: Failed loading page http://localhost?navi=45564574853&page=1§ion=&subsection=&frompage=1&subsubsection=&topage=7&webpage=foobar&time=14:28:00&date=18/06/2014 (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --ignore-load-errors)

Comment: The error is thrown at this point:
header('Content-Type: '.$mime.';charset=utf-8');